# how to send structure in C using UDP sockets without serialization?

Tags: c, sockets, udp

I am trying to send a structure in C without using serialization

```
// client
typedef struct student_rec {
char name[25];
float gpa;
int pid;
} stu;

stu stu = { "Ray T Champion" , 4.0 ,  12345666};

sendto(sk,&stu,sizeof(struct student_rec),0,&remote,sizeof(remote));




//server
typedef struct student_rec {
char name[25];
float gpa;
int pid;
} stu;

stu s ;
struct student_rec *ptr;
ptr = &s;
recvfrom(sk,&s,sizeof(struct student_rec),0,&remote,&rlen);
printf("%s\n", ptr->name);
printf( "%d\n", ptr->pid );
```

I recieve the name just fine , but the pid is not correct, I get garbage values, I am not concerend about endianess, I would just like to be able to send the struct in one shot.

Comment: Please show the structure, and what `stu` is (on both sending and receiving side).

Comment: Also, are the sending and receiving program on the same type of system? Or are they using e.g. different type of processors? You might want to read about [endianess](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianess).

Comment: This `ptr = &s;` doesn't look nice. Doesn't the compiler complain on it?

Comment: I'm a little tired so didn't see your note about endianess, but maybe you *should* be concerned about it? What platform (OS and CPU architecture) do you have on the sending and receiving sides? And please *edit your question* to include all relevant information instead of adding it as comments.

Comment: server is sun , client is linux , i should receive the pid in reverse order... but i do'nt even get that i get 1113701376

Comment: Which pid did you expect though?

Comment: If its 12345666, then just convert both values to hex and become enlighted.

Comment: The next problem you'll face (after the endianness problem) is when the sending computer's compiler (or compiler settings) pads the struct differently from the receiving computer's compiler (or compiler settings).  Sending the entire struct in one go is fragile; don't expect it to work in the general case.

Answer (score 3):

You face an endianess issue.

You send `12345666` which is the same as `0x00BC6142`

and you receive `1113701376`  which equal to `0x4261BC00`.

Before sending convert to network byte order by

```
stu.pid = htonl(stu.pid);
```

After receiving convert (back) to host byte order.

```
stu.pid = ntohl(stu.pid);
```

Comment: I see now , I was expecting to get the decimal back in reverse not the hex and I am printing the hex in decimal .....  thanks , i am now enlightened

Comment: @spacemonkey: If you fell this answers your question, mark it as such by clicking the answer's check.mark. This way SO can indicate the issue as solved.